# Length of Yield Return

Tags: c#, yield-return

Is there a way to get the number of yield returns from within a function **without keeping a counter variable?** For instance?

```
  IEnumerable<someobject> function
  {
      for loop
          yield return something

      int numberreturned = ....
  }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That would defeat the purpose of [`yield return`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx).

Using `yield return` means you want to implement a generator (MSDN calls that an *iterator block*), i.e. an object that computes every value it returns *on the fly*. By definition, generators are potentially infinite, and therefore control might never leave your `for` loop.

Streams work the same way. To compute the length of a stream, you have to exhaust it, and you might never return from doing that. After all, the data could come from an infinite source (e.g. [/dev/zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/zero)).

Answer (score 2):

**No. This is not possible without a counter** -- *there is no way to access the returned stream from within the function itself*. (If it were possible, I wonder what sort of strange semantics/quirks it would entail?)

However, this is perfectly okay (if questionable) with a counter, even if the question does not desire such a response ;-) Remember that this form of construct is "magic" around closures invoked when the next item in the stream (iterator) is required -- that is, flow control *leaves* and *re-enters* at the `yield return` as required.

```
IEnumerable<someobject> Function
{
  int counter = 0;
  foreach (...) {
      counter++;
      yield return ...;
  }
  // after here we know count -- /assuming/ control gets here
  // 1) value can't be 'normally returned'
  // 2) and if the stream evaluation never exhausts the loop above
  //    then flow-control will never get here
}
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the extension method count on the the IEnumerable<> that your function returns

```
function().Count()
```

Comment: This will work on the methods *return* value -- but will *force evaluation* (which may never terminate).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`IEnumerable.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) extension method!

I think that `yield return` is intended for the compiler to implicitly build a basic iterator using the statement that follows it.

If you want a more complex iterator then you might implement that in a more explicit manner.

Comment: This will work on the methods *return* value -- but will *force evaluation* (which may never terminate).